# User-configurable routes in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a requirement that portions of the pages in my web app need to be accessible through a user-specified URL path.

For example, I have a route like: `/cars/view/volvo` which would go to CarController and the view method and pass volvo as a variable. However, I have the requirement that a user can set a custom URL for this resource, e.g.:

`/super-shiny-cars/volvo-x90`

This will be stored in the database. How can I make CakePHP route user-specified, custom URLs like this to the right controller / method?

Comment: Your question is not  clear. For this "/super-shiny-cars/volvo-x90", what will be your controller and what will be your method??? Give example with domain name, so that it will be clear to understand. @Mark

Comment: It will be the old controller (CarController#view). The idea is to allow users to set which URL path points to which controller and method.

Comment: Considering your Domain Name as www.xyz.com
You want, something like,  www.xyz.com/super-shiny-cars/volvo-x90

If there will be controller exist it will go to the controller method other wise it will load /cars/view with params "super-shiny-cars" and "volvo-x90". Right? @Mark

Comment: Yup - that is correct